# Force composition refresh

Tags: javascript, durandal

I have a route (doctors/:id) that contains two subpages (doctors/:id/index and doctors/:id/details). This is my shell.html:

```
<div id="content-head">
   <h1>Page Title</h1>
</div>

<div id="content-main">
   <ul class="tabs" data-bind="foreach: router.navigationModel()">
      <li data-bind="css: { selected: isActive }"><a data-bind="attr: { href: hash }, text: title"></a></li>
   </ul>

   <div id="content-main-inner" data-bind="router: {}"></div>
</div>

<aside data-bind="compose: { model: 'doctors/_sidebar/index' , view: 'doctors/_sidebar/index' }"></aside>
```

The sidebar composition includes page related information, such as stats and links to other `:id` pages.

I'd like to keep the sidebar intact when navigating between the two subpages, but when I go from `doctors/100` to `doctors/200`, I'd like for the sidebar to refresh and give me new data. Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: You want it to "refresh", or do you simply need the bindings to update with the new data?  Your view model should handle the changes in the data and update the bindings accordingly.

Comment: I want it to execute the code inside the sidebar's `activate` again so it could get data according to the new ID. I just found a way to do that by adding `activationData: [router.activeInstruction().params]` to the composition, which returns the ID. But that also fires every time I change tabs, even though the ID stays the same.

Comment: I would suggest that you refactor your `activate` and take the data loading code out of that, then put it in a new function (called by activate as necessary).  Then use the Durandal eventing to subscribe to an event, and reload the data on that event.  Then in your other "subpages" trigger that event when they load, or activate, or whatever.

Comment: See: http://durandaljs.com/documentation/Leveraging-Publish-Subscribe/

Comment: So here's what I did. I changed my shell to this: http://snippi.com/s/ug9fo15 – and then I just subscribe to that trigger in the sidebar composition, right?

Comment: That looks about right.

Comment: Awesome! Post your answer so I could accept it. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest that you refactor your activate and take the data loading code out of that, then put it in a new function (called by activate as necessary). Then use the Durandal eventing to subscribe to an event, and reload the data on that event. Then in your other "subpages" trigger that event when they load, or activate, or whatever.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an if binding around your compose and toggle it like this:

```
<!-- ko if: $root.composeDimensionListShow -->
                    <!-- ko compose: here-->
<!-- /ko -->
```

with javascript like:

```
 vm.composeDimensionListShow = ko.observable(false);
 vm.composeDimensionListToggle = function () {
    vm.composeDimensionListShow(true);
    vm.composeDimensionListShow.valueHasMutated(); //knockout will normally not update if it is already true, but we want to refresh every time regardless
};
```

The other answer may be better for some situations, but in situations where it is not practical to do this, this is a lot simpler and answers your question more precisely.

Just call compositionlisttoggle() when you want to refresh the compose.